# RSS/Atom feed parsing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, rss, feed, atom-feed

What is the best library to parse a feeds (RSS,Atom...) in Haskell?

I'm especially interested in the points:

- Performance/memory
- Encoding issues for non-English characters?
- Correctness, detection of feed-type (RSS 1, RSS 2, Atom...), handling of non-valid feeds, etc.

I already stumbled upon [feed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/feed), however it uses `String`s. How can this affect performance/memory, especially if `ByteString.Lazy` or `Text` are used elsewhere throughout the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is right about trying to avoid `String`. The general rule of thumb in modern Haskell is to avoid `String` whenever you can and use `Text` or `ByteString` instead. However in this case, I'm not aware of any direct drop-in replacement for the `feed` package.

In practice, because parsing feeds is usually network-bound, you shouldn't have any performance issues under normal circumstances.

However, if you really need high throughput and tight control of resources, it shouldn't be too difficult to write your own RSS parser using [`xml-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit), which I'd say it's the most mature *iteratee-based* XML parsing library out there. You can have a look at how it's being used by [these packages](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/xml-conduit).

Comment: Thank's a lot. I already played around with ´xml-conduit´, but was afraid of handling edge-cases correctly, etc.